# Where do electrons derive from

Tags: electrical-resistance

I was thinking recently that electrical wire carries electrons right that travel to the positron and push each other and get hot from the tension but since my house wires connect to a sub station where does the substation get all the electrons to send out... like a car battery too how does it start just from a battery full of liquid

Comment: You should start with an elementary physics course, the rudiments of atoms and matter. There are no positrons floating around matter. There are electrons and nuclei for an atom, the nuclei composed of positve charge protons and neutral neutrons. Atoms  are neutral . If an electron is taken off a nucleus, then it is an ion of positive charge equal in magnitude to the electron negative charge...... http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where does the substation get all the electrons to send out

They are already in the wires.

Think about a wire that you run a magnet along. The moving magnetic field drags the electrons along inside the wire. That's all a power plant is, something turning a magnet beside a bunch of wire.

The electrons don't move all the way from the plant to you. When the magnet moves an electron from A to B, there's now two electrons at B. That extra force causes some other electron to move from B to C, which causes one at C to move to D. And so on, and so on...

It's like a water wave. The water isn't moving from the lake to you, it's just moving back and forth. It's the *wave* that's moving, or in the case of electrical power, the voltage.